# Radio button animation , transition not working

Tags: html, css, css-animations, css-transitions, css-transforms

```css
.container3 {
  padding: center;
  height: 100vh;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: center;
}

.container3 .materiali {
  padding: 8px 48px;
  margin: 8px;
  font-family: Baskerville;
  font-size: 25px;
}

input[type="radio"] {
  display: none;
}

label {
  position: relative;
}

label::before {
  content: "";
  background: url("check-circle.svg");
  background-position: center;
  background-size: contain;
  width: 32px;
  height: 32px;
  position: absolute;
  left: -45px;
  top: -1px;

  transform: scale(0) rotateZ(180deg);
  transition: all 0.4s cubic-bezier(0.54, 0.01, 0, 1.49);
}

input[type="radio"]:checked + label::before {
  transform: scale(1) rotateZ(0deg);
}

label::after {
  content: "";
  border: 2px solid #27ae60;
  width: 24px;
  height: 24px;
  position: absolute;
  left: -42px;
  top: 1px;
  border-radius: 50%;
}
```

```html
<div class="container3">
  <h1>LOREM IPSUM</h1>
  <div class="materiali">
    <input name="lpselection" id ="lp-selection-0" value="whatever" type = "radio">
    <label for="lpselection-0">whatever
    </label>
  </div>
  <div class="materiali">
    <input name="lpselection" id ="lp-selection-1" value="idk" type = "radio">
    <label for="idk">idk
    </label>
  </div>
  <div class="materiali">
    <input name="lpselection" id ="lp-selection-2" value="iirc" type = "radio">
    <label for="iirc">IIRC
    </label>
  </div>
  <div class="materiali">
    <input name="lpselection" id ="lp-selection-3" value="lastone" type = "radio">
    <label for="lastone">lastone
    </label>
  </div>
</div>
```

Now I was trying to perform a transition on these radio buttons the same as I was performing a transition like this in the checkboxes (my previous post) however , again , transition wont work. Code , I suppose , doesn't have any problem , since I am using the same one for my checkboxes group and it works, however I'm afraid I havent probably ordered "input" and "label" correectly, even though they have to be right under each other, no ? What is going wrong here ?

Comment: This will not solve your entire problem, but when using a label's for attribute you have to give it the associated elements id. For instance, instead of <label for="idk"> you would need <label for="lp-selection-1">

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your culprit is syntax errors in your `for` and `id` attributes primarily. See example below.

I used a unicode checkmark for the example since don't have the svg (which you could [encode to include directly into the css](https://www.svgbackgrounds.com/tools/svg-to-css/) if you wanted by the way), any other minor changes were simply for the sake of example. Cheers.

```css
.container3 {
  padding: center;
  /*height: 100vh;*/
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: center;
}

.container3 .materiali {
  padding: 8px 48px;
  margin: 8px;
  font-family: Baskerville;
  font-size: 25px;
}

input[type="radio"] {
  display: none;
}

label {
  position: relative;
  cursor: pointer;
}

label:before {  
  content: "";
  z-index: 1;
  color: red;
  font-size: 2.5rem;
  background: url("check-circle.svg") center / contain no-repeat;
  width: 32px;
  height: 32px;
  position: absolute;
  left: -40px;
  top: -13px;

  transform: scale(0) rotateZ(180deg);
  transition: all 0.4s cubic-bezier(0.54, 0.01, 0, 1.49);
}

input[type="radio"]:checked + label:before {
  transform: scale(1) rotateZ(0deg);
}

label:after {
  content: "";
  border: 2px solid #27ae60;
  width: 24px;
  height: 24px;
  position: absolute;
  left: -42px;
  top: 1px;
  border-radius: 50%;
}
```

```html
<div class="container3">
  <h1>LOREM IPSUM</h1>
  <div class="materiali">
    <input name="lpselection" id="lp-selection-0" value="whatever" type="radio">
    <label for="lp-selection-0">whatever</label>
  </div>
  <div class="materiali">
    <input name="lpselection" id="lp-selection-1" value="idk" type="radio">
    <label for="lp-selection-1">idk</label>
  </div>
  <div class="materiali">
    <input name="lpselection" id="lp-selection-2" value="iirc" type="radio">
    <label for="lp-selection-2">IIRC</label>
  </div>
  <div class="materiali">
    <input name="lpselection" id="lp-selection-3" value="lastone" type="radio">
    <label for="lp-selection-3">lastone</label>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

The transition doesn't work. I inspect a little bit, and I see that you put an image on label::before which it does not load. Second it's not the correct method, you should use ::checked on input and style with CSS. You put a transition on :before that is not triggered. You can use transition on :hover for example.